# Download file using node js from "non-file" url

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, download

I am trying to download file from other website using node js but the url given by the website is like https://download-sample.com/video/vide_title/mp4/.

I have tried using [url-download](https://www.npmjs.com/package/url-download) but it returns other page,  it says like that I need to register to donwload it. It's like checking my session when I access the download URL.

Is that possible to download a file from other website and set the session, so I can download that file?

Comment: You need to send a `Cookie:` header.

Comment: how can i do that inside of http.get() ?

my current code : 

`var file = fs.createWriteStream("file.mp4");
var request = http.get("https://download-sample.com/video/vide_title/mp4/", function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});`